# DocuSign 404 error when trying to get jwt

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to test out Docusign on prod, these are the details I am providing the (python) docusign client:

```
from docusign_esign import ApiClient

ds_app = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
        client_id=INTEGRATION_KEY,
        user_id=USER_ID,
        oauth_host_name=BASE_PATH,
        private_key_bytes=RSA_PRIVATE_KEY,
        expires_in=3600,
        scopes=SCOPES,
    )
```

The BASE_PATH was calculated using:

```
GET https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/login_information
```

It looks like:

```
na3.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/MYACCOUNTNUMBER
```

The output is a 404:

```
(404)
Reason: The URL provided does not resolve to a resource.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you have is the top level for eSignature API calls to this account, but by itself does nothing (Except give you 404).
There are resources under it, try to put `/envelopes` for example and do a get or `/users` and do a GET and see if you don't see a 404.

The full list of endpoints can be found in the [DocuSign eSignature API Reference](http://na3.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/MYACCOUNTNUMBER).

The `oauth_host` parameter for production is `account.docusign.com,` but for developer it's `account-d.docusign.com`.

Comment: That link you sent me doesn't seem to work. Additionally, I am simply calling the request_jwt_user_token method provided by the python client. what should the url be set to for that?

Comment: URL To do what? get a JWT token? you don't need to make API calls directly if you are using the Python SDK (client). 
or are you asking about URLs to make API calls? where do you see a URL parameter that you don't know how to fill?

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python/blob/47107f1a733c970e10d8fc3e47be0a2bdb677014/app/docusign/ds_client.py

Comment: this has Python JWT example

Comment: the URL for oauth_host_name, is that what you are asking?

Comment: oauth_host_name, yes

Comment: account.docusign.com

Comment: just that, no https or anything

Comment: for production it's account.docusign.com, but for developer it's account-d.docusign.com

Comment: if that's what you mean, I can modify my answer, I thought you are asking something different.

Comment: ah, thank you. I am getting no_valid_keys_or_signatures but that must be related to some set up that I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238850/discussion-between-harveyslash-and-inbar-gazit).

Comment: Edited my answer to address other things.